# Comparing ASP.Net Framework to Cakephp, Zend , Ruby on Rails

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I am a PHP developer migrating to C# ASP.Net Framework. As of right now, I am experienced in using Php for developing sites and I use CakePhp and Zend framework as my RAD tools to help me produce better applications.

As I move over to ASP.NET, I have this view that C# ASP.Net framework itself is already a RAD tool and is  equivalent to using Cakephp, Zend, or even Ruby on Rails. So I really shouldn't have no concerns trying to find a separate library for ASP.NET that will help me produce better applications. To me, in a sense the ASP.NET is already like a MVC cause it seperates the model from the view and the methods are almost like controllers.

So as far as having the best tools are concerned, should I be satisfied with just using ASP.NET as my RAD tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look into ASP.NET MVC, too.  Compare between Web Forms (regular ASP.NET) and MVC to see what method would be easier for you to follow